NANITE feature of Unreal Engine in Blender 4.2?
Is there any feature or addon for Blender 4.2 that works like the NANITE feature in Unreal Engine?
to use extremely dense meshes in polygons?
thanks

No. There isn't even a Nanite feature in other game engines. It's a pretty cutting-edge feature that Unreal developed themselves. You can look into a Decimate modifier, to cut down the number of polys in your mesh. But that doesn't work in real time like Nanite does.

Do you believe that triangulating the mesh optimizes the use of the EEVEE GI viewport in Blender 4.2? Are there any palliative measures in this regard?
What about the procedural maps of the materials? Is it appropriate to bake them to optimize the use of the EEVEE GI? Thanks
